# How to center a div in another div using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I want to make a header image with a semi circular bottom. In the middle of this image I want a title and a button. I can't manage to center the div with the title and button using just flexbox or bootstrap. mx-auto (margin x auto) works but my-auto doesn't, align-self-center and align-items-center classes doesn't work, I have to add mx-auto. To center the circular bottom I have to use margin-left: -25vw. What is the best way to center te divs?

This is my code:

```css
.image-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.circular-bottom {
  width: 150vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin-left: -25vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circular-bottom img {
  z-index: -1;
}

.title-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="circular-bottom d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="url/image" draggable="false">
   </div>
   <div class="title-box d-flex">
    <div class="title-text align-self-center">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <a class="btn" href="#">button text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image-wrapper prevent the horizontal scroll. The circular-bottom makes the bottom of the image circular using overflow hidden, it's wider for the shape of the circle. This is also the reason the image isn't a background image, it have to be cut off by using overflow hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `justify-content: center` property to the flex container (`.title-box` in this case) should work, like this:

```css
.image-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.circular-bottom {
  width: 150vw;
  height: 90vh;
  margin-left: -25vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circular-bottom img {
  z-index: -1;
}

.title-box {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-text {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div class="circular-bottom d-flex justify-content-center">
    <img src="url/image" draggable="false">
   </div>
   <div class="title-box d-flex">
    <div class="title-text align-self-center">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <a class="btn" href="#">button text</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have already tried it and It's working for me.

Link to the working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YLOwxX